# SQLite3 Javascript | Change data in database for every row

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, discord.js

What I need to do is remove 30000 from a count and that for every single data in my database.
Example:

```
User1 | 520000
User2 | 230000
User3 | 670000
User4 | 262000
```

->

```
User1 | 490000
User2 | 200000
User3 | 640000
User4 | 232000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET x=x-30000`?

Comment: I downvoted this post, because it does not contain any information about what you have tried so far, what you have googled, and what it is that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `update` statement:

```
db.run('UPDATE mytable SET col2 = col2 - 30000');
```